# Family of straight lines

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have an expression:
$a^2(4-x^2) + b^2(9-y^2) + ab(12-2xy) = 0$
Is it a family of straight lines of the form: $L_1 + \lambda L_2 + \mu L_3 = 0$. If yes, on dividing the whole expression by first by $ab$ and subsequently by $\frac{a^2}{ab}$, $L_3$ comes out to be $xy=6$ which is a hyperbola.If no, why? Or is it a family of pair of straight lines?

Comment: Expand... you will recognize $(2a+3b)^2-(\cdots)^2=(A-B)(A+B).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it as
$$(a(2-x)+b(3-y))\cdot(a(2+x)+b(3+y))=0,$$
which can be identified as a pair of lines when $a\neq 0$ or $b\neq 0$. If $a=b=0$, then the set of solutions is the whole $xy$-plane.